# split string using to words using the empty spaces and storing them in a list using python

Tags: python, string, list

for example i have this string :
ch = "promotion bac 2019"
and an empty list :
t=[]
i want to make the list get each word separately using the empty spaces
result will be :
t=["promotion","bac","2019"]
i tried deleting each word from the string after storing it in the list but i didn't work properly . dont mind looking at my code its really bad

```
def splitword (ch,t):
    i=0
    while len(ch)!=-1:
            if ch[i]== " " :
                t.append(ch[0:i])
                ch=ch.replace(ch[0:i],"")
            else : 
                i=i+1 
            
t=[]
ch = "promotion bac 2019"
splitword (ch,t)
print(t)
```

Comment: there already is a function to do this - `t = ch.split()`

Comment: that add a string between words i need to extract each word and  store it in a list

Comment: It gives you exactly the output you say you're after.

Comment: otherwise you should explain what "i didn't work properly" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the fixes for your code

```
def splitword (ch,t): 
     i=0 
     while i != len(ch): 
         if ch[i]== " " : 
             t.append(ch[0:i]) 
             ch=ch.replace(ch[0:i+1],"") # need to add 1 for the end position
             i = 0  # reset position
         else :  
             i=i+1
     if ch:  
        t.append(ch)  # add the last word
t=[] 
ch = "promotion bac 2019" 
splitword (ch,t) 
print(t)
```

But from my side of view the @Sayse has gave you good advice about the `split` function.

Answer (score 0):

To split a string into words delimited by space you can use `s.split(' ')`.

However, if want to implement the code to perform the splitting then can iterate over the string for each character and check if that character is a space or not then assemble the words.

```python
def splitword(s):
  w = ''
  words = []
  for ch in s:
      if ch == ' ':
          if len(w) != 0:
              # have a new word to add to list
              words.append(w)
              # clear w for next word
              w = ''
      else:
          # append character to next word
          w += ch
  # check last word
  if len(w) != 0:
      words.append(w)
  return words
  
s = "promotion bac 2019"
t = splitword(s)
print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
['promotion', 'bac', '2019']
```